# update file in Document library

Tags: sharepoint, document, event-receiver

I am working on a requirement event receiver generates page content into **Microsoft Word** and **PDF** using a third party DLL. Once the generation is completed I need to upload it to document library.

This happens on `ItemUpdated` and code works fine when the doc or pdf files are not in the library but when they are created and I have to update them it throws an error.

```
 ex = {"The file \"http://www-mylab.com/en/home/Documents/James-bond_1033.pdf\" is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes."}

   web.Files.Add(wordFileUrl, wordStream, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to turn of the "Require Checkout" setting on your [document library versioning settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-library-HA101853103.aspx).

Otherwise you will have to call the [CheckInFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkinfile%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [CheckOutFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkoutfile%28v=office.12%29.aspx) members of the SharePoint [Lists webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774654%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: No need for the webservice if you're using the Server object model as the question suggests. `SPFile f = web.GetFile(wordFileUrl);     f.CheckOut();` should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, there needs to be more info because the question does not suggest use of the SharePoint OM to me... In which case *much* more help is required.

Comment: Doesn't web.Files.Add(url,stream,boolean) look like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412937(v=office.12).aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using SharePoint's server object model.

```
SPFile f = web.GetFile(wordFileUrl); 
f.CheckOut(); 

web.Files.Add(wordFileUrl, wordStream, true);

f.Checkin("new version");
```

should do the trick